# Excel VBA: fill textbox based on combobox selection

Tags: excel, vba

First off all I am not very experienced with excel VBA. After searching on net and youtube I couldn't figure it out, so I hope you can help me out.

In my workbook I run a macro that gives a timestamp via =NOW() and an "unique" generated code via CHAR(RANDBETWEEN). This is then copy & pasted to a separate sheet("Dates")to create the list for my combobox, where the code is in column A and the timestamp in column B. Each time I run my macro a new timestamp and code is generated and put in Row 1 Column A & B again (so the older one is shifted down)

With the combobox I got my list of timestamp based on the code below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet, lirow As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dates")
lirow = 1
While ws.Cells(lirow, 2) <> ""
Me.cboxDates.AddItem ws.Cells(lirow, 2).Value
lirow = lirow + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

What I want is to show the corresponding code in a textbox next to my combobox, so basically just an offset (0, -1).

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Kr, Marty

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub cboxDates_Change()
  Dim Found As Range, LastRow As Long
  Set Found = Worksheets("Dates").Columns(2).Find(what:=Me.cboxDates.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
  If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Me.TextBox1.Text = Worksheets("Dates").Cells(Found.Row, Found.Column).Offset(0, -1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time to answer my question. I have tried a less sophisticated code but the issue I ran into is (sorry for not explaining earlier) is that the NOW() is copy & paste "value" into the cells so they cant change. With the find function I run into the problem that it doesn't recognize my dates. I believe this is casued by the way excel stores dates? Is there a way around this ? I have tested it with non-dates data and it works beautifully, so thanks a lot :).

Comment: did u try setting the format of the column as some specific date format ?

Comment: I have the column in date: 3/14/01 1:30 PM

Comment: the cell shows example: 10/5/16 3:28 PM, but If I click on the cell it contains 10/5/16 3:28:29 PM, so seconds are added, which is also see as the option in my combo box

Comment: If I copy & paste cell into the find option it will select the cell, but if I copy & paste the underlying it doesn't. I also now added a custom option to add the :ss (seconds), so if I look at cell and in the bar it reflects the same value and if I

Comment: Got the solution, I changed the add.item.value to .text in my combobox code and now the textbox if filled, Thank you so much! for your code!